# Website translation check

Tags: multilingual, service

I hope that it is not so stupid question but is there some service or forum where another users (native speakers) can check and review my translated web site? I don't want to check dozens of pages but only few sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found this: www.mylanguageexchange.com
I hope that it will be no problem to review my translation for someone from that site and I can improve my language skills too, so one day this reviews will not be needed.

At this time, it seems the best solution for my needs. Anyway, if you find something better, I'll be glad. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck asking my users to improve translations for me.  On one site, I asked users to email me any improvements to the translations.  On other site I built an interface that allowed them to enter improvements one sentence at a time.  Most of the popular languages have now been completely rewritten by native speakers, just because I asked.

Comment: Interesting, the only user generator-ed content I get is on my wiki and even then its poor, you must have a good user base.

Comment: thank you, but I need to be the translation correct because its commercial site, so I can't rely on my users